# What is the callback for responsive.details.renderer() function in jQuery datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, datatables, renderer

**Datatatable initialization:**

```
$('#tblEmployee').DataTable({
        "bDestroy": true,
        responsive: true,
        "order": [[0, "desc"]],
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "lengthMenu": [[5]],
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sEmptyTable": "No records found !",
        },
        "processing": true
});
```

In responsive view of datatable, when user clicks on "Plus" symbol, it renders the child rows having ".child" class inside table.
Here, I need to call call a javascript function to disable the controls of the datatable.
I need to disable the controls only when the datatable is collapsed.

```
function disableCtrlInsideDT(){     
      $('.dataTable.collapsed').find('input:checkbox, input:button, select, button').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

I have written an external CSS as well, but it's not working as expected. I mean, the CSS disables the control but the "not-allowed" cursor doesn't work at that time.

```
.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed tbody tr { cursor: pointer !important; pointer-events: none !important; }
```

So, I need a callback where I can write all the javascript methods, that should be fired after rendering of child rows.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle to let us debug better?

Comment: Hi @Akhoy, Thanks for your reply. 
Sorry I have no idea about how to post a fiddle. I am trying to do it. But for now, here is a link for your better understanding.

[link_DataTable](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html)

As we have "page.dt" event which is the callback of pagination, "drawCallBack" which is a callback of draw() method.. 
    $('#tblEmployee').on('page.dt', function () {
            // javascript code here
     });Similary I need a callback method/event when user clicks on "Plus" symbol of datatable in mobile view.

Answer (score 3):

You can handle [`responsive-display`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/responsive-display) event when details for a row have been displayed, updated or hidden.

For example:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    responsive: true
} );

table.on( 'responsive-display', function ( e, datatable, row, showHide, update ) {
    console.log( 'Details for row '+row.index()+' '+(showHide ? 'shown' : 'hidden') );
} );
```

However it's not clear why would you want to disable clicks on `(+)` control, I will leave it up to you.

Comment: Thank you very much @Gyrocode.com.. It worked for me..
Actually there are  6 dropdowns and 8 multiselect-dropdowns in one datatable. In mobile view, it looks bit wierd and on the top of that is very difficult to handle by end user.
So, temporarily I am disabling those controls in mobile until we'll have a stable UI.

Comment: This is great. Thank you for the callback example!